# Pandas: Delete Rows in a dataframe if specific columns don't contain specific text

Tags: python, pandas, delete-row

I have a df

```
     id  column_int column_int  column_A column_B column_C column_D
 0   1        int       int         ABC     ABC     Keep      na
 1   2        int       int         ABC     ABC     ABC       ABC
 2   3        int       int         ABC     Save    na        na
 3   4        int       int         ABC     Keep    na        na
 4   5        int       imt         ABC     ABC     ABC       ABC
 .
 .
```

Where `column_int` are columns that contain ints and `column A-D` contain text values. I want to keep only the rows that have either `Keep` or `Save` as row values

Before:

```
 id  column_int column_int  column_A column_B column_C column_D
 0   1        int       int         ABC     ABC     Keep      na
 1   2        int       int         ABC     ABC     ABC       ABC
 2   3        int       int         ABC     Save    na        na
 3   4        int       int         ABC     Keep    na        na
 4   5        int       imt         ABC     ABC     ABC       ABC
```

After:

```
 id  column_int column_int  column_A column_B column_C column_D
 0   1        int       int         ABC     ABC     Keep      na
 2   3        int       int         ABC     Save    na        na
 3   4        int       int         ABC     Keep    na        na
```

I tried the following

```
for column in df:
    if type(column) == object:
        df = df[df[column].str.contains('Save')] | df[df[column].str.contains('Keep')]
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use use [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on the selected columns, then for each column check for `Save` or `Keep` by [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html).  Then, use [`.any()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) on `axis=1` (for row-wise operation) to check if the row contains such strings.

Finally, filter by [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), as follows:

```
cols = ['column_A',  'column_B',  'column_C',  'column_D']

df.loc[df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(r'Save|Keep')).any(axis=1)]
```

**Result:**

```
   id column_int column_int.1 column_A column_B column_C column_D
0   1        int          int      ABC      ABC     Keep       na
2   3        int          int      ABC     Save       na       na
3   4        int          int      ABC     Keep       na       na
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe easier and clearer to do without the for-loop.

```
dfA = df.loc[(df.column_A == 'Save') or (df.column_A == 'Keep')]
dfB = df.loc[(df.column_B == 'Save') or (df.column_B == 'Keep')]
dfC = df.loc[(df.column_C == 'Save') or (df.column_C == 'Keep')]
dfD = df.loc[(df.column_D == 'Save') or (df.column_D == 'Keep')]
```

Then concatenate the dataframes together

```
df = pd.concat([dfA, dfB, dfC, dfD])
```